# How show image from a data base into a picturebox, C# and Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, picturebox

That's my question, i have a image in a database, and  I want that picture to be displayed in a picturebox, examples will serve me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image tempImage;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("myconnectionstring"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SprocToGetImageBytes", conn) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
        {
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var buffer = (byte[])rdr[0];
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                {
                    tempImage = Image.FromStream(ms); //theres your image.
                    pictureBox1.Image = tempImage;
                    pictureBox1.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```